# STA(Internet)/STA(ultrasonic device) concurrency

Tags: wi-fi, tablet

I would like to pair an ultrasound device (AP) to a tablet via a 5GHz wifi (at 40 MHz) connection. At the same time the tablet should connect via 2.4 or 5 GHz wifi to the internet (AP). Unfortunately I cannot combine those 2 connections into one wifi, because if I do, the MDR (Medical Device Regulation) of the ultrasound device will be violated and it can't be legally used without a new certification.
On top of that I need to use both connections simultaneously, because the transmitted ultrasonic pictures (which are displayed on the phone via an app) are to be streamed over the internet connection to a PC.

So summarized I have to APs and one STA device to connect simultaneously.

I have found an android interface named [STA/STA Concurrency](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/wifi-sta-sta-concurrency), which if I'm not mistaken should do the job.
The problem I have now is, that I don't find a STA/STA Concurrency supported tablets or to be more precise I don't find any information about which device is supporting the STA/STA Concurrency.

The STA/STA Concurrency states that it needs/prefer:

- a 2x2+2x2 DBS Chip module
- the APIs "IWifiChip.setMultiStaPrimaryConnection()" and "IWifiChip.setMultiStaUseCase()" and
- the HAL Wi-Fi interface combination must have two concurrent STA interfaces exposed
  But again the manufactures do not show such detailed information.

Some Android phones have a dual-band WLAN option (like the Asus ZenFone 8) with which you can connect a 2.4 and 5GHz WLAN separately. Unfortunately, I can't find any information if these connections can be used simultaneously. [YouTube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AsaD2YdNkyU)

[Somebody on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73540418/android-automotive-aosp-how-to-enable-and-test-ap-ap-sta-sta-sta-ap-concur) tried to create a STA/STA Concurrency with a [automotive wifi chip](https://www.nxp.com/products/wireless/wi-fi-plus-bluetooth/2-4-5-ghz-dual-band-2x2-wi-fi-6-802-11ax-plus-bluetooth-5-3-automotive-solution:88Q9098). But there is no solution either.

Does anybody have a solution for this problem? Hardware or Software, I don't care as long as it works (the tablet will be just a first prototype).

(As an alternative I thought about using a windows tablet, put in 2 wifi cards, install Android (or Linux if necessary and a android emulator for the ultrasonic app) and assign the wifis accordingly. But there again, I need a tablet with 2 separate antennas.)

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I know this is kind of a half hardware question, so off-topic. I tired it on Hardware recommendations, but nobody has a solution to this. But since this can maybe be solved via software, somebody over here can help me.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know about STA. May be you are lucky and the awaited Pixel Tablet is released in time for you. Usually Google's Pixel devices support the features Google develops for Android, so hopefully this will also be true for STA. Alternatively you could search for an HW-info app that prints out the result of `WifiManager#isStaConcurrencyForLocalOnlyConnectionsSupported()` and then make a quick tour through some large electronic shops that present running tablets you can test yourself.

Comment: Cross-posted from HardwareRecs.SE for hardware-based solution: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/16472/364

Answer (score 1):

@Ben1401 I know it's late for this answer but Pixel 6a and 7a have the functionality that you are talking about.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/271014975#comment33
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232107693#comment5